# how to create multiple values for the name column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset has this form:

```
name = c("h", "s", "i", "s", "o","R")
value = c(37, 27, 20, 20, 5, 5)
df = data.frame(name, value)
```

I tried every idea that I could, but I think that I am missing some basic knowledge about how to solve it.
    adding stats = "count"

```
 ggplot(df,aes(name) ) +
     geom_bar(stat = "count", show.legend = TRUE)
```

I am obtaing or:
- A plot with all the columns
- Error messages

My expected solutions is:
A barplot using ggplot, with 4 columns as 
"h", "s", "i & s", "o & R"

And in y-axis, each of the columns with the next values: 37, 27, 20, 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After summarising the data as suggested by @caldwellst, you could plot the bar plot using

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarize(name = toString(name)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(name, value, label = value, fill = name) +
  geom_col() + geom_text(nudge_y = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust your dataset prior to plotting, as `ggplot` has no idea that you want to visualize identical values as a single bar. Using `dplyr` you could simply do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarize(name = paste(name, collapse = " & "))
```